# Numba very slow with default arguments depending on which arguments are provided

Tags: python, numba

I'm implementing a function for which some arguments are compulsory and some are set as default in numba, however depending on the values set for the default arguments, which order the different types appear in and which arguments are provided I am getting very different timings:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def function(a, b, c, d=1.49012e-8, e=1.49012000000001e-8, f=0.0, g=None):
    ...
        
@nb.njit
def function2(a, b, c, d=1.49012e-8, e=1.49012000000001e-8, f=0.0):
    ...
        
@nb.njit
def function3(a, b, c, d=1.49012e-8, e=1.49012000000001e-8, f=None, g=0.0):
    ...

@nb.njit
def function4(a, b, c, d=1.49012e-8, e=1.49012e-8, f=0.0, g=None):
    ...
```

And then timing it with different numbers of `args` and excluding different `kwargs`:

```
d = 1.49012e-8
e = 1.49012000000001e-8
f = 0.0
g = 1000

args = (d, e, f, g)
kwargs = {'d': d, 'e': e, 'f': f, 'g': g}

def time_func(func, args, kwargs):
    func(1, 2, 3)
    
    print(func.__name__)
    print("time *args")
    for i, _ in enumerate(args):
        func(1, 2, 3, *args[:i])
        %timeit -n 1000 func(1, 2, 3, *args[:i])
    print("time **kwargs")
    for i in kwargs:
        _kwargs = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k != i}
        func(1, 2, 3, **_kwargs)
        %timeit -n 1000 func(1, 2, 3, **_kwargs)

time_func(function, args, kwargs)
time_func(function2, args[:-1], {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k != 'g'})
time_func(function3, args, kwargs)
time_func(function4, args, kwargs)
```

Output:

```
function
time *args
26.3 µs ± 425 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
25.4 µs ± 266 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
24 µs ± 175 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
241 ns ± 4.94 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
time **kwargs
235 ns ± 2.03 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
23.7 µs ± 62.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
23.3 µs ± 203 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
241 ns ± 5.25 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
function2
time *args
24.1 µs ± 115 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
23.3 µs ± 172 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
22.1 µs ± 428 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
time **kwargs
210 ns ± 1.31 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
22.6 µs ± 97.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
21.9 µs ± 98.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
function3
time *args
26.3 µs ± 149 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
25.2 µs ± 81.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
24 µs ± 160 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
23.3 µs ± 416 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
time **kwargs
237 ns ± 4.64 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
25 µs ± 290 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
255 ns ± 12.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
24.2 µs ± 112 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
function4
time *args
26.2 µs ± 238 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
25.1 µs ± 95.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
24.1 µs ± 250 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
240 ns ± 5.87 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
time **kwargs
231 ns ± 11.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
233 ns ± 3.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
23.4 µs ± 132 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
230 ns ± 3.43 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

I've tested with numba 0.58.0 in python 3.11.5 and numba 0.57.1 in python 3.10.12 and get similar results in both.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the timings. On my machine it takes always the same time (+/- 1%) but it is MUCH slower : 15.9 **ms** instead of **µs**. I use Numba 0.58.1 and Python 3.8.1 (more specifically ipython) on Windows. PS: this is certainly due to the sleep function which takes at least several milliseconds on Windows probably due to the quantum of the scheduler. I expect a similar issue on Linux with a significantly smaller granularity.

Comment: If I remove the `sleep` calls, then the effect is also visible and similar on my machine, but the gap is even bigger (60x slower for some cases : 1 µs versus 60 µs).

Comment: Ok, I've removed the sleep calls, and updated my timings

Comment: Reproduced the results on my system. If I'm not mistaken, with "dynamic" inputs like this, numba generates enough code to handle all possible combinations of signatures. My (uneducated) guess would be that this behaviour is caused by how the compiler decides to order this code, i.e. how long you need to search until you hit the correct signature. Have you inspected the IR?

Comment: @simeonovich if I look at `function.inspect_llvm()` there are only 7 signatures it has been compiled for, I don't think it should take ~20us to search that.